# PHP 7.0, APCu and APC Backward Compatibility installed. Where has apc.rfc1867 gone?

Tags: php, file-upload, php-7, apc

We've successfully installed APCu and apc-bc against PHP 7.0.16 and phpinfo() shows both as loaded, as follows:

> ### apc
>
> APC Compatibility 1.0.3
>
> APCu Version 5.1.8
>
> Build Date Feb 16 2017 19:19:59

However, neither the **apc** nor the **apcu** section shows the apc.rfc1867 values (as apcu 4.0.10 did in PHP 5.6)

And when trying to run our code against this PHP 7.0 implementation the following error displays:

> PHP initialisation variable apc.rfc1867 must be set to 1

But the rfc1867 related values *are* set as follows in our php.ini: (this works perfectly against PHP 5.6)

> apc.rfc1867=1
>
> apc.rfc1867_freq=0

The apc.rfc1867 functionality is really important to us and any help in understanding where we're going wrong would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

After following unsuccessful attempts at achieving a solution from both the PHP team - [bug 74131](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=74131), and from the apc development owner - [issue 22](https://github.com/krakjoe/apcu-bc/issues/22), we have been forced to conclude that apc.rfc1867 is non-functional as at PHP 7 and have therefore migrated away from apc.